# "Pour tes 1 an" : usage du pluriel

Tags: grammaire, expressions, pluriel, nombres

Bonjour,

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi on utilise "1 an" au pluriel dans des formules comme : "pour mes/tes/nos/vos 1 an de..."?

Comment: Je crois qu'on utilise pour mon un an